# PCB Trace Width for 100A High Current

Tags: pcb

I'm designing an high power H bridge inverter able to supply up to 100A sinusoidal current.

Is it possible to carry this current levels on a PCB? Eventually, can you suggest me the trace width and thickness?

I've also read about bus-bar. Is it preferable for my application?

Any suggestion are welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: Look for photos of circuit boards that are used in BLDC motor drivers for scooters and electric bicycles.  You will see that they use copper buss bars on top of the PCB traces to handle the large currents involved.

Comment: Which trace calculators did you try?

Comment: for how long... I use PCB to carry 100A but its all about duty

Comment: They are sinusoidal currente not continuous.

Comment: You should get a ball-park figure for the size of conductor that you need. If we look for a table of [AWG vs current](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html) we see that a single copper wire of approximate diameter 5 mm would be used for that as a continuous rating. Would you modify your question now that you have that information?

Comment: But is the sinusoidal current continuous or only conducting for a short period... This is the difference between 2oz copper, 15mm wide and a 2mm thick busbar. Also the fundamental frequency is key

Comment: What are you using for connecters?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer, the current capability of a PCB track is limited by the temperature that it will reach when a current flow through it. Than, to exactly know the performance of a trace carring high current you need to simulate it. But it is not an easy task, because of the varius physical parameters involved in this process.

As a rule of thumb, I will suggest you to consider 60A/mm^2 as a limit value for polygon shape with a form factor 1:2. A normal trace (long and thin) is another kind of problem, but normally on this kind of inverter PCB the layout shape are not tracks.

You can read this article for an introduction on this topic
[Efficient Tool Sizes High-Current PCB Traces - Paul Schimel](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a2AwMmc7kV4J:https://www.electronicdesign.com/boards/efficient-tool-sizes-high-current-pcb-traces%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=it&client=firefox-b-ab)

Comment: At these currents, I'd expect the component connections to be the limiting factor.